# turn off progressbar when new window is fired

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two forms. `MainForm` and `ProductDetailForm`

Inside `MainForm` there is `txtSearchBox` input box and some radio values to filter search. When search is performing `progressbar` is displayed. Initially progress bar is set to `Visible = false;`

On btnSearch click event I'm calling background_worker to perform search. Immediatly progressbar is set to Visible = true.

When data is found and new window (`ProductDetailForm`) is opened on the MainForm progressBar is still visible, so my question is how to set Visible to false when new window is opened.

```
private void bntSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   progressBarControll.Visible = true;
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
   MyData data = repository.GetData(1);
   // tried here  progressBarControll.Visible = false;
   // but it raises an exception
   var detailsForm = new ProductDetailForm(data);

}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     progressBarControll.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: It raises an exception because you can only access properties of a UI element from the thread that control was created on.  Take a look at `Form.Invoke`.

Answer (score 1):

You can move both opening the new form and hiding the progress bar to `RunWorkerCompleted` method:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
   MyData data = repository.GetData(1);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
     progressBarControll.Visible = false;
     var detailsForm = new ProductDetailForm(data);
}
```